# Appended Children not recognized by Container

Tags: jquery, css

I have an issue trying to figure out why my `container` doesn't recognize that it has `children`. The children expand past the grid and does not work. I tried creating an unordered list for the children (appended values) but that did not work. How can I resolve this issue?

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bdfndp9h/1/

```
<div class="container text-slim">
  <div class="box square">

      <ul class="no-style">
        <li class="sub-container-title">Additional Item Specifics <i class="fa fa-info-circle" aria-hidden="true" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Use this to track listings using your own Product Identification Number (PIN)."></i></li>
        <li class="sub-container-input add-more-half">
          <div class="inputs_container"></div>
          <input type="text" name="text_area" class="text_area add-more-input ib" placeholder="Add your own item specific" maxlength="30" />
          <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-default add_input_submit ibb" type="button">+</button>
           </span>
        </li>

        <li class="sub-container-input add-more-half">
          <div class="checkbox_container"></div>
          <input type="text" name="text_area" class="text_area add-more-input cb" placeholder="Add additional accessories" maxlength="30" />
          <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-default add_checkbox_submit cbb" type="button">+</button>
           </span>

        </li>
      </ul>

  </div>
</div>
```

Tried adding this to my `CSS` but this did not help either

```
.no-style {
  height: auto;
  list-style: outside none none;
  margin: 8px 0 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

These are the `children` that leave the box container when appended or the `+ button` is clicked

```
    var input_content = $('.ib').val();
    $('.inputs_container').append('<ul class="no-style added-container input-group" id="newinput'+countinput+'"><li class="added-input-title">'+input_content+'</li><li class="added-input-body"><input type="text" class="add-more-input ib" id="input'+countinput+'"><span class="input-group-btn"><button class="btn btn-default ibb" id="inputbutton'+countinput+'" onclick="removeinput('+countinput+')" type="button">-</button></span></li></ul>');
    $('.ib').val('');
});

    var input_content = $('.cb').val();
    $('.checkbox_container').append('<ul class="no-style added-container input-group" id="newcheck'+countcheck+'"><li class="added-checkbox-body"><input type="checkbox" id="check'+countcheck+'"><span>'+input_content+'</span><span><button class="no-border" id="inputcheck'+countcheck+'" onclick="removecheck('+countcheck+')">x</button></span></li></ul>');
    $('.cb').val('');       
});
```

Comment: What is the issue, your facing ?

Comment: I can't get the height of the box to auto adjust when I click the "+" which appends or adds more values to the container. The new values just overflow the box container.

Answer (score 2):

Just remove `height: 50px;` from your `.sub-container-input` li

[Working Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/nk2sjcw8/)

Comment: @user2680614 do it have any problem?